# How do I get the value of onclick from a button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

The question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415606/get-the-value-of-onclick-with-jquery), except I need to use Javascript. I have a button like so:

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="clickhandler()">Test</button>
```

I need this for verification purposes, i.e. to assign the click handler, and then use javascript to verify that the correct function was assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED - totally misunderstood your question...

You want to know if you can verify which handlers are assigned to which tags programmatically...  gotcha...

So if you try:

document.getElementById("myButton").onclick.toString();

You'll see that what you get is:

```
function onclick()
{
    YOUR METHOD NAME HERE
}
```

I'm sure you can take it from there...  everything between "function onclick\n{" and "\n}" is your method.

Sorry I misunderstood your question originally!

B

Answer (score 1):

Just do the same, but in pure javascript:

```
var onclick = document.getElementById("btn1").onclick;
```

Comment: It should be: var onclick = document.getElementById("btn1").onclick; You capitalized the 'd'

Answer (score 0):

you could use getAttribute:

```
var anc = document.getElementById("anc");
alert(anc.getAttribute('onclick'));
```

Comment: Tried document.getElementById('anc').getAttribute('onclick')); and it didn't work. I didn't see getAtrribute support the onclick property, so I posted this question :(

Comment: I don't think the getAttribute cares about the name of the attribute you're trying to get.... try this http://jsbin.com/etawel/edit