# Get values out code block of a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I looked into google and found an approach of what I trying to do here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415606/get-the-value-of-onclick-with-jquery) but now I'm stuck. I'm using jQuery to get the value of the onclick function, but I need some inner code out of the Info function.

Here is what I get from $('a.turqheadlabel'):

```
[<a href=​"#" onclick=​"Info('another-ending')​" class=​"TurqHeadLabel">​ANOTHER ENDING ​</a>​,
<a href=​"#" onclick=​"Info('good-ending')​" class=​"TurqHeadLabel">​GOOD ENDING ​</a>​ ]
```

I used $('a.turqheadlabel').attr('onclick') and I get this:

```
function onclick(event) {
    Info('another-ending')
}
```

What I look is get the another-ending and good-ending so I can put them in an array that I need to call.

PS. If there is a way to avoid using eval is preferable since chrome will block it next year.

Comment: What do you want to do with the extracted values? Chrome extensions do not have direct access to any global variables. So, even if you manage to get "another-ending" and "good-ending", you cannot just put `Info(value);` in the content script. The most effective solution really depends on your use case, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

#### On a website you control

Assuming you want to access the value you're passing to `Info` (`'good-ending'` and `'another-ending'`) then you'd be better off using [HTML data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) and accessing the values using [jQuery's `data` function](http://api.jquery.com/data).

If you re-write your HTML to look like this:

```
<a href='#' class='TurqHeadLabel' data-info='some-ending'>SOME ENDING</a>
```

Then you can add your `onclick` handlers dynamically, and also easily access your `info` values in other places. This will attach the `onclick` handlers when the DOM is ready:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.TurqHeadLabel').click(function () {
        Info($(this).data('info'));
    });
});
```

Elsewhere in your JavaScript you can always access the `data-info` attribute using something like this:

```
myLink.data('info');
```

#### In a Chrome extension

You could temporarily replace the `Info` function with something that captures the values that is passed to it:

```
function getInfoParam(func) {
    var originalInfo, result;

    originalInfo = window.Info;
    window.Info = function (arg) {
        result = arg;
    }
    func();
    window.Info = originalInfo;

    return result;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression to find a quoted string:

```
function getInfoParam(func) {
    var match;
    match = func.toString().match(/"([^"]*)"/);
    if (match) {
        return match[1];
    }
}
```

This implementation is limited: It won't work for strings that contain escaped quotes (e.g. `"foo\"bar"`), or strings that are delimited by single quotes (e.g. `'foobar'`).

Whatever you do will be vulnerable to changes in the host website, and therefore somewhat fragile.

Comment: That approach I can do if I was the webmaster, now I'm trying with .tostring() and .replace() to clean the object and is working (somehow). I would like to don't abuse it (I call replace 4 times) so any other solution is appreciated.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you're writing a Chrome extension (I didn't notice the tag). I've updated my answer with some alternative techniques.